# Как по событию OnDismiss диалога изменять переменную во фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

Есть cardview по нажатию на который открывается диалог. Столкнулся с проблемой, что при быстром нажатии открывается 2 диалога. Поискав нашел способ, присвоив `cardview.iseneble = false`, и после onDismiss в диалоге ставить значение true. Пытался реализовать  `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener { cardView1.isEnabled = true }` , но **cardview** так и оставалось false.
Как по событию onDismiss изменить на true?

```
        when (tag){
        "bottomSheepFragment" -> {
            cardView1.setOnClickListener {
                cardView1.isEnabled = false
                DialogFragment.show((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager, "1")
                DialogInterface.OnDismissListener { cardView1.isEnabled = true }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если диалог в фрагменте то можно при закрытии фрагмента вызывать onActivityResult:

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.putExtra("close", true)
targetFragment!!.onActivityResult(0, Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
Objects.requireNonNull<FragmentManager>(fragmentManager).beginTransaction().remove(this).commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

и ловить в фрагменте:

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            0 -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        cardView1.isEnabled = true
                    }
                }
            }


        }

}
```

Так же есть вариант - активировать виджет через некоторое время. Добавить таймер и по истечению времени просто активировать виджет.Так же у диалога есть такой метод который отслеживает показ:

```
DialogInterface.OnShowListener {  }
```

То есть когда диалог будет показан то можно будет активировать виджет. Я допускаю что ваш метод скрывания диалога не работает из-за того что ему нечего перехватывать. Так же в активности можно использовать `onActivityResult`